# Firebase & website relationship information scramble

Tags: javascript, html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER7sp.png)I just connected my website to firebase to login users but seems to me whenever a user registers on my website the information they put into my website gets scrambled the moment it enters firebase database

this is my code snippet of the js file

```
//save message to firebase
function saveMessage(Name, Surname, Email, Number, Country, Verpasswrd, Username, Birthday) {
    var newMessageRef = messagesRef.push();
    newMessageRef.set({
        Name: Name,
        Surname: Surname,
        Birthday: Birthday,
        Email: Email,
        Number: Number,
        Country: Country,
        Gender: Gender,
        Verpasswrd: Verpasswrd,
        Passwrd: Passwrd,
        Username: Username,
    })
}`
```

[![firebase output result][2]][2]

Comment: Show us the code in `SaveMessage`

Comment: i havent fully understood stackoverflow of how i can edit and add code but i added an image for convenience

Comment: Well I could only say that the code look right. Maybe that the parameters is wrong. eg name is eq to mail instead and so on. You should have a look on that.